# Exist a particular format of the Regular Expressions in VS2010?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use Regular Expressions to search all Optional Argument across the solution(all my parameters have the prefix prm).

```
AccessModifier NameOfMethod(sometype prmParam1, bool prmFlagOrSomething = false)
```

My E.R is: **prm\w+\s=\s\w+**

In Notepad++ works fine and catch "prmFlagOrSomething = true", but when I tried in VS2010, "Ctrl + Shift + F" + "Use: Regular Expressions" don't find anything.

I need a particular format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio has its own strange regex dialect, for details see [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The problem in your expression is that it does not know the predefined classes `\w` and `\s`

try (not tested)

```
prm[a-zA-Z0-9]+:b=:b[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: Works, thank.
Then the Regular Expressions are not standardized?

Comment: No, nearly every language has its small differences (Basic features are normally the same), but Visual Studio has a big difference.